# Eclipse equivalent to changelists in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea, changeset

In [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html#changelists) there's an option to group files (local) changes in changelists

> All changelists are displayed in the Local Changes tab of the Version Control tool window Alt+9. All modified files are automatically placed in the active changelist, which is the Default changelist unless you have created a different one and made it active.

Is there equivalent feature/plugin in eclipse?

We want to organize our changes before pushing to git server

Comment: To do what? In Git, it's best practice to develop separate features on separate branches (have a look at how Gerrit does it). If you've made different changes (e.g., doing clean-up/refactoring work independently of the feature), split the changes into different commits. As long as you haven't pushed, you can change the order of commits and squash multiple commits in the _Rebase Interactive_ view. But if you know it in advance, use different branches, because splitting into multiple commits can result in an inconsistent state when you revert a single commit of them.

Comment: @howlger I think you are correct, if you write an answer I'll accept it

Comment: This is a relevant question, I use change lists a lot to keep track of things like local changes for my dev environment, stick them in a change list so they don't interfere with my actual changes I'm working on. And I usually have several of those for the different things I needed to tweak locally.

Comment: An approximation to changelists could be [Git stashes](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#stash-via-the-git-repository-view). Although they are organized as stack per branch (auto-indexed but also can give names), you can stash your uncommitted changes and come back to it later.